# How can i Center-Justify text

Tags: html, css

How can I justify the text with using `text-align` css property in the span?

```
echo "<span style = 'font-size: 18px; color: #000097; font-weight:  bold;'>"
```

Comment: This is CSS 101 stuff.

Comment: Plus, technically speaking, your code is missing both a double quote and a semi-colon, IF that's your real code.

Answer (score 1):

Use css property `text-align:justify` and `display:block`.

```
<span style = 'font-size: 18px; color: #000097; font-weight:  bold; text-align:justify; display:block;'>
```

> Here we need to use `display:block` because `<span>` is inline element so we converted it to block element with `display:block`

If you are applying on block element in future no need to use `display:block`.

Here is a working fiddle with current situation : https://jsfiddle.net/26pwac9y/2/

Comment: [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) only applies to "block containers". [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements are "inline" by default. [Example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/26pwac9y/)